# Find all possible pairs and store in a list of list of list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, list

for the following df

```
Names        Henry    Adam   Rachel  Jug   Jesscia  May   Peter
Robert         54      0        0     6       5      8      24
Dan            22      31       0     0       55     4       8
```

I want to find all possible pairs of the columns with numeric values (Henry,    Adam,   Rachel,  Jug,   Jesscia,  May,   Peter,) in the following df and append their values as a list of list of lists.

**for eg:**

```
[[[54,22],[0,31]], [[54,22],[6,0]]......]
```

where [54,22],[0,31] is the first pair
I will greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to get only the numeric columns, then [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) (`T`) and convert the DataFrame `values` into a list. Lastly use [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to get all possible pairs of length 2:

```
from itertools import permutations

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Names': ['Robert', 'Dan'], 'Henry': [54, 22], 'Adam': [0, 31],
    'Rachel': [0, 0], 'Jug': [6, 0], 'Jesscia': [5, 55], 'May': [8, 4],
    'Peter': [24, 8]
})

output = list(
    map(list,
        permutations(df.select_dtypes(include='number').T.values.tolist(), 2)
        )
)
```

`output`:

```
[[[54, 22], [0, 31]],
 [[54, 22], [0, 0]],
 [[54, 22], [6, 0]],
 [[54, 22], [5, 55]],
 [[54, 22], [8, 4]],
 [[54, 22], [24, 8]],
 [[0, 31], [54, 22]],
 [[0, 31], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 31], [6, 0]],
 [[0, 31], [5, 55]],
 [[0, 31], [8, 4]],
 [[0, 31], [24, 8]],
 [[0, 0], [54, 22]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 31]],
 [[0, 0], [6, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [5, 55]],
 [[0, 0], [8, 4]],
 [[0, 0], [24, 8]],
 [[6, 0], [54, 22]],
 [[6, 0], [0, 31]],
 [[6, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[6, 0], [5, 55]],
 [[6, 0], [8, 4]],
 [[6, 0], [24, 8]],
 [[5, 55], [54, 22]],
 [[5, 55], [0, 31]],
 [[5, 55], [0, 0]],
 [[5, 55], [6, 0]],
 [[5, 55], [8, 4]],
 [[5, 55], [24, 8]],
 [[8, 4], [54, 22]],
 [[8, 4], [0, 31]],
 [[8, 4], [0, 0]],
 [[8, 4], [6, 0]],
 [[8, 4], [5, 55]],
 [[8, 4], [24, 8]],
 [[24, 8], [54, 22]],
 [[24, 8], [0, 31]],
 [[24, 8], [0, 0]],
 [[24, 8], [6, 0]],
 [[24, 8], [5, 55]],
 [[24, 8], [8, 4]]]
```